# Why Path.Combine not working in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am creating Windows Phone 8 app. In that I've `Util` static class. Now while creating database, I've kept database name as `const string` & database path as `static string`, when I try to combine it, it gives me incorrect path, WHY? See below image for proof. What's wrong with my code.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `Path.Combine()` with one parameter, which will just return the input. Change `+` to `,` to pass it two parameters, which will cause it to combine the paths.

Also try to copy+paste relevant code, that reads a whole lot easier than a screenshot.